# Oracle Cursor Is Not Working as Expected

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, cursor

Here is the procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE provsnXmlCmprsn (
            encyNo SAS_PRO_CTL.AGENCYNO%TYPE, period SAS_PRO_CTL.PERIODE%TYPE) IS

xmlContent SAS_PRO_XML.XMLCONTENT%TYPE;
sasProvisionId SAS_PRO_CTL.SASPROVISIONID%TYPE;

CURSOR crsrXml IS
SELECT XMLCONTENT, c.SASPROVISIONID FROM SAS_PRO_XML x, SAS_PRO_CTL c
  WHERE x.SASPROVISIONID = c.SASPROVISIONID AND c.PERIODE = period 
                                    AND c.AGENCYNO = agencyNo ORDER BY XMLLINENO;

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Params: ' || agencyNo || ', ' || period);

OPEN crsrXml;
LOOP
  FETCH crsrXml INTO xmlContent, sasProvisionId;
  EXIT WHEN crsrXml%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('XML Content Length: ' || LENGTH(xmlContent));
END LOOP;
CLOSE crsrXml;

END provsnXmlCmprsn;
```

The query in the `cursor` is retrieving 5 rows, whereas 1 row is expected, according to the condition and argument values. The same query results in 1 row, when run independently. And the surprising part is, the query in the `cursor` always return 5 rows no matter if the condition, `c.PERIODE = period AND c.AGENCYNO = agencyNo`, passed or not. Which clearly means that this query,

```
SELECT XMLCONTENT, c.SASPROVISIONID FROM SAS_PRO_XML x, SAS_PRO_CTL c
  WHERE x.SASPROVISIONID = c.SASPROVISIONID AND c.PERIODE = period 
                                    AND c.AGENCYNO = agencyNo ORDER BY XMLLINENO;
```

and this query,

```
SELECT XMLCONTENT, c.SASPROVISIONID FROM SAS_PRO_XML x, SAS_PRO_CTL c
  WHERE x.SASPROVISIONID = c.SASPROVISIONID ORDER BY XMLLINENO;
```

are behaving same inside the `cursor`. This, `AND c.PERIODE = period AND c.AGENCYNO = agencyNo`, part is not at all considered. **Any idea what's going wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your parameters has the same name as the column: AGENCYNO.  Because of the way scoping works this evaluates to `1=1`.  This is why it is good practice to give parameters unique names, for example by prepending them with `p_`.

You should find that

```
AND c.PERIODE = p_period AND c.AGENCYNO = p_agencyNo
```

returns the desired one row.  Strictly speaking you don't need to change the name of `period` to `p_period` because it is already distinguished from `periode`.  But consistency is a virtue in software engineering.

Comment: APC beat me to it.  He's apparently far more caffeinated than I at the moment.

Comment: @JustinCave - actually the first tea of the day is cooling unsipped on the table ;)